# If one root of the equation $x^2+px+1=0$ be the square root of the other then find the value of $p$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

If one root of the equation $x^2+px+1=0$ be the square root of the other then find the value of $p$.

My Attempt:

Let $\alpha $ and $\beta $ be the two roots of the given equation. Then,

$$\alpha =\dfrac {-p + \sqrt {p^2-4}}{2}$$
$$\beta =\dfrac {-p-\sqrt {p^2-4}}{2}$$.

According to Question:
$$\alpha =\sqrt {\beta}$$
$$2p^2-2p\sqrt {p^2-4} - 4=-2p-2\sqrt {p^2-4}$$

How do I proceed further?

Comment: Why do you assume alpha is the square root of beta and nor the other way around?

Answer (score 2):

The roots are $a$ and $a^2$ so $$a^3=1$$ and 
$$a+a^2=-p$$ so either $a=1$ and $p=-2$ or $$a^2+a+1=0$$ in which case $p=1$.

Comment: How is.$a^3=1$?

Comment: If the roots are $a$ and $a^2$ then the factors are $x-a$ and $x-a^2$. Multiply them together.

Answer (score 0):

So the roots are $r$ and $r^2$. Then the equation is $(x-r)(x-r^2)=0$,
that is $x^2-(r+r^2)x+r^3=0$. So you need $p=-(r+r^2)$ and $1=r^3$.
So what is $r$, and what then must $p$ be?

Comment: why are $r$ and $r^2$ roots?..and please explain the other steps as well.

Comment: @Maxwell if the first root is the square root of the second, then the second is the square of the first.

Comment: And how do you get $p=-(r+r^2)$ and $1=r^3$?

Comment: If it makes you more comfortable (but it shouldn't-- this should both be equally clear)  you could let one root be $t$ and the other $\sqrt t $.  Then you must solve $\t\sqrt t=1$ and $p=-(t+\sqrt t) $.  But that is the *exact* same thing with $t=r^2$.

Comment: @fleablood, solving this way gives $p=-2$ but the answer in book is $1$.

Comment: @Maxwell That's what I get when I expanded $(x-r)(x-r^2)$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, what answer did you get? I got $-2$.

Comment: @Maxwell Don't forget that numbers have three cube roots in the complexes. When $p=-2$ we get the repeated root $1$. I reckon that $1=\sqrt1$.

Comment: The book is assuming complex roots???  If p=1 and x^2+x+1=0 then $x =-1/2 \pm i\sqrt {2}/2$ a non real complex root.  The two solutions are both squares and square roots of each other.  The book probably had another method it had taught you to use.

Comment: $r^3=1$ has one real solution and two complex solution.  If r is real then r =1 and p=-2.  If r is complex $r+r^2=-1$ so p=1.

Comment: If we assume the solutions are $r $ and $r^2$ AND we assume $r\ne r^2$ (i.e. "the other") than $r\ne 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Vieta's formulas:

a = 1, b = p, c = 1 for your equation ($x_1 = \sqrt{x_2}$)

$x_1x_2 = \frac{c}{a} = 1 = x\sqrt{x}$, thus $x = 1$.

$x_1 + x_2 = -\frac{b}{a} = -p$

$1 + 1 = -p$, thus $p = -2$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the roots are $\alpha$ and $\alpha^2$, then, 
\begin{align}
&(x-\alpha)(x-\alpha^2)=0 \\
\implies&x^2+x(-\alpha-\alpha^2)+\alpha^3=0 
\end{align}

Comparing this with $x^2+px+1 = 0$ we get:
\begin{align}
&\alpha+\alpha^2 = -p \\
&\alpha^3=1
\end{align}

If we cube the first relation of the two above, we discover an interesting relation:
\begin{align}
&(\alpha+\alpha^2)^3=-p^3 \\
\implies&\alpha^3+\alpha^6+3\alpha^4+3\alpha^5=-p^3 \\
\implies&a^3+a^6+3\alpha^3(\alpha+\alpha^2) = -p^3 \\
\implies&1+1+3(-p)=-p^3 \\
\implies&p^3-3p+2=0 \\
\implies&(p-1)(p^2+p-2)=0 \\
\implies&(p-1)^2(p+2)=0
\end{align}

Clearly for p to satisfy this $p=1$ or $p=-2$